# Dynamically rearrange country drop down based on location via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I have a drop down full of countries and country codes. The list is pretty big, so I wanted to put the visitor's country at the top dynamically after the page loads. Is there a way to do this in jQuery (GeoIP?)?

My drop down looks like this:

```
<select name="country" id="country" class="inputCombo">
    <option value="">Select an item...</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    ....
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
</select>
```

If you are in the US, then I'd want it to rearrange like this:

```
<select name="country" id="country" class="inputCombo">
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="">--------------</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    ....
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
</select>
```

Or if in Canada, like this:

```
 <select name="country" id="country" class="inputCombo">
        <option value="CA">Canada</option>
        <option value="">--------------</option>
        <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="AL">Albania</option>
        <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
        ....
        <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
    </select>
```

Any suggestions or tricks for this?

Comment: Which server side language are you using? You probably can do it server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below basically does the following:

1. Call a location api that supports jsonp (i.e. ???)
2. On success, find an option element with matching value
3. Move it to the top by prepending to the select
4. Change the text of the 'blank' option to '----'

I have no idea if the location service used is accurate or what it's usage policy is. You should also cache the value for a time to prevent excessive api calls. Additionally, this code does not check that it *can* find an option with matching country code. You should check that before rewriting the 'blank' option (or forget rewriting it)

Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/rob_cowie/uZLNM/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <select name="country" id="country" class="inputCombo">
        <option value="">Select an item...</option>
        <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="AL">Albania</option>
        <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
        <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="US">United States</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var url = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?';

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON(url)
            .success(function(data){
                var country_code = data.geoplugin_countryCode;
                var $country = $('#country');
                $country.find('option[value="'+country_code+'"]').prependTo($country);
                $country.find('option[value=""]').text('--------------');
                $country.val(country_code);
            });
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```